# Change background image on hover and keep active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to all this and was hoping for some help. I want the background to stay after you hover one of the links. Also is it possible to make a fade/transition on the background when appearing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#change').hover(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("http://i.imgur.com/cyxXVpT.jpg")');
    }, function() {
        $('body').css('background', '');
    });
    
    $('#change2').hover(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("http://i.imgur.com/5MupbQ2.jpg")');
    }, function() {
        $('body').css('background', '');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="change2">Change2 </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background to stay, just use the mouseenter event only

```
$('#change').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("http://i.imgur.com/cyxXVpT.jpg")');
});
```

If you want fading backgrounds, you can use css transitions

```
-webkit-transition: background ease-in 1s;
-moz-transition: background ease-in 1s;
-o-transition: background ease-in 1s;
transition: background ease-in 1s;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpo02dxy/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep the background don't use the 2nd parameter of hover function
The first parameter of over is when you hover the object and the second on blur.
https://api.jquery.com/hover/
It's possible to fade in using animate function
https://api.jquery.com/animate/

EDIT: or a transition with css like adeneo said